# AWS SDK constant unresolved identifiers in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

I was following the instructions from Amazon Web Services to set up AWS SDK following steps from the site below:
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html

I installed the AWS frameworks via cocoa pod. I get a problem when copying this code from the page into Appdelegate.swift. The defined constants of CognitoRegionType, CognitoIdentityPoolId, and DefaultServiceRegionType raise the error unresolved identifier.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

However the constant credentialsProvider seems to exist, so can anyone point out where I may be making a mistake? In some other examples I've looked at CognitoRegionType, CognitoIdentityPoolId, and DefaultServiceRegionType seem to be established constants upon importing AWSCore.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the things which you need to substitute based on your configuration from AWS Console. For e.g. If your Cognito Identity Pool is in US East 1 (N. Virginia), the CognitoRegionType will be .USEast1. The CognitoIdentityPoolId can be found in the Amazon Cognito Console. The service region is the region where all your resources lie.

Thanks,
Rohan

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate like this in your **didfinishlaunching** method,I have converted my code in swift 3.0-

```
var credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.usEast1, identityPoolId: "us-east-1:f53e36d5-****-****-****-bd42d4ca4489")
//Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
var serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.usEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
var analyticsConfiguration  = AWSMobileAnalyticsConfiguration()
analyticsConfiguration.serviceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration
var analy = AWSMobileAnalytics.init(forAppId: "appid", configuration: analyticsConfiguration)
```